# Map function sort only one result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx

I need to map in movieinfos, which is filled by 7 movies data.

The problem is that it renders only one movie data card.

When I look at the console.log just before the return, I have the 7 movies in movieinfos.

Why does map function create only one card? The created card concerns the first movie in movieinfos if it could help.

```
function App() {

  const [movieid, setMovieid] = useState([]);
  const [movieinfos, setMovieinfos] = useState([]);
  let moviesData = [] 

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response.data.movies)
    
    
      setMovieid(response.data.movies)
    
    
  })

  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
     
  
}, []);

console.log(movieid)

useEffect(() => {
for (const movie of movieid) {
console.log(movie.movieid)
 axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${movie.movieid}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=fr`) 

  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response)
    
    moviesData.push(
    {Genres: response.data.genres,
      Overview: response.data.overview,
      Poster: response.data.poster_path,
      Company: response.data.production_companies,
      Release: response.data.release_date,
      Title: response.data.title}
      )
    setMovieinfos(
      moviesData
      );
      
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })

  }

}, [movieid]);

useEffect(() => {
console.log(movieinfos)
}, [movieinfos]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Header">
        <Logo />
      </div>
      <div className="Menu">
        <Search />
        <Add_movie_button />
        <Delete_movie_button />
        <Random_movie_button />
      </div>
      <div className="Movies">
        
        {movieinfos.map((movie) => <Movie_card key={movie.Title} data={movie}/>)}
         

      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you try adding round brackets inside your map() function?
`{movieinfos.map((movie) => (<Movie_card key={movie.Title} data={movie}/>))}`

Comment: What you basically do is; you make a detail reqeust for each movie asynchronously then you `setMovieinfos` with the results independently. So you override the state and end up having the data of the latest result. I suggest you update the related part of `moviesInfo` state, something like {movieId, details}

Comment: Nothing changes :(. Thanks for your help however  Nitin